# Write mix node (tag + text )replacing only specific node

Tags: html, xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo, jaxp

I have a loop between child nodes 
I can have word a fo:block than another word like:

```
<mynode>
Hi ok 
<fo:block>
hi ok fo block
< /fo:block>
maybe another text node here...
</mynode>
```

I have to replace `<fo:block>` with `<div>` but i have to leave text in the same position (before and maybe after fo:block if it exists)

I try this code but  (suppose to loop child (*) nodes):

```
<xsl:for-each select="/mynode">
  <xsl:if test="text()"><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></xsl:if>
  <xsl:for-each select="child::*"> 
    <!--for every child node of mynode-->
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="normalize-space(local-name()) 
                      = normalize-space('block')"> 
        <xsl:call-template name="fo-block">
          <xsl:with-param .../>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:if test="text()"><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></xsl:if>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

if test= text() so node contains text then display text, otherwise i get the name of node and test if is a block: if so, i call a specific template otherwise a test if contains text.

Seems to work for now..So, could be the right choice/code for my scope?

thanks!

roby

Answer (score 0):

The problems that appear at first glance include:

- Your inner for-each loop loops over `child::*`, which will match every element child; it will not match any other children (text nodes, comments, processing instructions).  I think you meant `child::node()`.
- Your test for block elements (`"normalize-space(local-name()) = normalize-space('block')"`) is namespace-oblivious, so it is unnecessarily fragile.  The calls to normalize-space() are pointless, since local-name() never returns any string containing whitespace, and the literal string 'block' doesn't contain any whitespace.

  A shorter, more reliable test would be `test="self::fo:block"`.
- You say

  ```
  Seems to work for now..
  ```

  If your tests show this code working, your tests are not doing you as much good as they should.

The portion of your processing that you describe seems to amount to:  change `fo:block` elements to `div`; leave everything else the same.  The simplest way to approach such a transform is to write an identity transform and then add more specific rules to capture things that need to change.  For example:

```
<xsl:template match="fo:block">
  <div>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<!--* other non-identity processing goes here ... *-->

<!--* What we don't have specific rules for gets handled
    * by the following template and the default templates,
    * which together perform an identity transform. *-->

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
 <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the two templates matching `comment()` and `processing-instruction()`? These nodes are already handled by the identity transform template. AFAICT, the only effect of these templates is to produce an error message of "Error: Ambiguous rule match for ...".

Comment: I suspect that when I made my version of the identity transform years ago, I factored them out because I often want to treat them separately.  They aren't handled by the general rule I gave originally, because they don't match the match pattern `@*|*` (unless I'm missing something here).  But I can make your observation true, and remove them, if you like

Answer (score 0):

M .,

your schema and response was very useful

I add complexity to my fo:block translation: consider attributes replaced by html if im in a table  (in a fo:cell parent) i use div, otherwise(anywhere) p.. So, i make these changes, hope you are agree:

```
<xsl:template match="fo:block">

<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="parent::fo:table-cell">
<div>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
 </div> 
 </xsl:when>
 <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:if test="@space-before"> <!--  distance before is rep. by br -->
        <xsl:call-template name="count-br"> <!-- write a br tag for each unit -->
            <xsl:with-param name="howmuch"><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(normalize-space(@space-before),'cm')"/></xsl:with-param>  
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
 <p>
    <xsl:if test="@font-size">
        <xsl:attribute name="font-size"><xsl:value-of select="@font-size"/></xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="@text-align">
        <xsl:attribute name="text-align"><xsl:value-of select="@text-align"/></xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="@font-family">
        <xsl:attribute name="font-family"><xsl:value-of select="@font-family"/></xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>        
 </p>
 </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
```